# jQuery UI Datepicker: don't highlight today when it is also selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I'm using the [jQuery datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) to select dates.  It works fine, except there is 1 default behavior that I would like to change.  When you select a day, the selected day is highlighted (which I like).  The current day is also highlighted, but using a different css style (which I also like).  However, if you select the current day, the highlighting because it is the current day supersedes it being selected... I would much prefer it being selected to supersede the current day highlight, which I feel would make it very clear that you have selected the current day.

Now, I feel I could probably update the css to solve my problem.  However, I really don't want to tweak the out-of-the-box jQuery UI css, because I want to later add skins to my app.  This means if I grab a bunch of the jQuery UI themes... I then have to make the same tweak on all of them (very undesirable).

I could probably update the actual Datepicker plugin to do this as well, but then I run into the issue that if I want to update my Datepicker later on... I need to remember to make this fix again.

Ideally, I could use some option built into the Datepicker to accomplish my goal, but as of yet none of the options seem to be right.  I would settle for some kind of JavaScript hack, or css plopped into the page, but I'm at a loss for ideas right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding an additional CSS file to your page would definitely be the preferred method.  It's easily managed and uses CSS the way it was intended to be used!

You would need to place your override CSS in the head tag after any previously loaded base jQuery CSS or any theme CSS files in order to override their values.  (You could also increase the specificity of the default tag, referencing a class or ID in your specific instance.)

i.e.

```
<head>
  <link href="base_jquery_css_file" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="theme_jquery_css_file" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <link href="your_override_css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

The "your_override_css" file would simply contain:

```
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active {
  /*any CSS styles you want overriden i.e.*/
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

---

**Note from Mike:**

I ended up finding out that there is a td around the anchors that represent the days, and the td also has the "today" information... so despite there not being a cross-browser way to select an item that has multiple classes (that I've found), the following will work in this case, in a new file just as PHPexperts.ca describes:

```
.ui-datepicker-today .ui-state-active {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, and is exactly what I wanted! thanks!

Comment: Really? This doesn't answer the question of having today unhighlighted and the current selection highlighted. Background doesn't seem to change even with !important as there are other classes at play. Also, I don't know what the non-selected style is.

Answer (score 0):

Since it took me a while to figure out how to exactly replicate the "selected" style over top of the today style even with the answer from PHPexperts.ca, here's a bit more information that might make it a bit more straightforward if you're having trouble.

If you select a day other than "today", the style that you should copy for an identical look when "today" is selected is in the `a` tag and in the selector

`.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active`

This should be easy to find if you have Firefox with Firebug installed (select the date, reopen the datepicker, right click and select 'inspect element'.

For the jQuery UI theme 'UI darkness' the style to copy into your override css is

`.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
background:url("images/ui-bg_inset-soft_30_f58400_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #F58400;
border:1px solid #FFAF0F;
color:#FFFFFF;
}`

If you change the theme, it looks like all 3 of  these styles change.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's quite easy, just add `!important` to the `.ui-state-active` class for the background and the border element.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-state-highlight {
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3 !important;
    background-color: #e6e6e6 !important;
}
```