# Prevent jQuery UI Datepicker (inline type) from selecting today's date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

jQuery UI Datepicker automatically selects today's date and sets it as value of associated input element. Is there a way to prevent this, apart from clearing the input field on [beforeShow](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow), like:

```
beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
    $('#calendar').val(''); 
}
```

...which is both dirty and bug-prone.

Documentation doesn't seem to list any method. There is [gotoCurrent](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-gotoCurrent), but it only moves the link to the currently selected date instead of today. What I want is to leave today's date unselected and associated input field blank.

However, I am not speaking of hiding today's date CSS class, which was already covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731018/jquery-ui-datepicker-dont-highlight-today-when-it-is-also-selected).

Note that this is the issue only with inline datepicker (bound to `div` or `span` elements). It doesn't happen with tooltip datepicker (bound to `input` element).

Comment: Never seen it automatically set a date when none is set in the input. Does not happen in demos in docs either https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/. Provide a demo that reproduces your issue

Comment: There is example on docs page itself, http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#entry-examples, titled A simple jQuery UI Datepicker. 

It gets initiated with just `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();` and it does select today's date. When you then type `$('#datepicker').val()` in console, you can see that the input's value is filled too. I am not sure if date is set in input beforehand, but I'd say it isn't.

Comment: That only highlights the current date...it does not set it as value

Comment: @charlietfl Looks like you are right, for the case when datepicker is attached to `input` element. However the issue is unfortunately still there with inline datepicker, which gets rendered when it is attached to `div` or `span` as per jQuery docs. I updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to prevent the highlight of today's date override the `highlight` class with same properties used for the default class

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

```css
.ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #454545;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
.ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #454545;
}
</style>

<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
```

Comment: But this won't highlight the current date if I selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var _date = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10) != _date]
  }
});
```

[**Online Demo (fiddlejs)**](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/wu4z2erL/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but returning false on `beforeShowDay` for today's date makes today's date disabled in effect, which is not what I want. I need it to remain selectable like other dates, I only need to prevent Datepicker from automatically selecting it.